# Добавить a href

Tags: jquery

Есть код, как добавить к  $('#openphone').html(data.phone); ссылку на телефон

```
 $('.btn-phone').click(function (e) {
        var el=$(this);
        var id=el.attr('id');
        var href=el.attr('href');
        if(href == '#'){
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: TPL_PATH + "ajax_data/phone/",
                cache: false,
                data: 'data='+id,
                success: function(data){
                    if(data){
                        if(data.hide == '1'){
                            alert(TPL_L_00);
                        }else{
                            if(data.phone != ""){
                                $('#openphone').html(data.phone);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
            e.preventDefault();
        }

    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> $('#openphone').html(data.phone);
> ```

```
$('#openphone').html($('<a>').attr('href', 'tel:' + data.phone).text(data.phone));
```

Answer (score 0):

Я не знаю, правильно ли отрабатывает весь код, но ссылку на телефон надо добавлять с приставкой tel

```
...
$('#openphone').html('<a href="tel:'+data.phone+'">' + data.phone + '</a>');
...
```